# Add Firebase to Angular 2 via NPM

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase

I'm currently learning Angular 2 and Firebase 3 and I've recently come across an `npm` package to install Firebase into Angular 2 which is [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/firebase-angular2).

However, inside that link, the individual is specifying that I add the paths to my `System.Config` which I do not have within my project due to being purely `typescript`.

Can someone please share some information in to how I go about getting this wired up without using `System.Config`?

I'm also using the `angular-cli`.

Comment: The link you provided says to use `<script src="https://cdn.firebase.com/js/client/2.3.2/firebase.js"></script>`. So it looks like the package hasn't been updated for Firebase 3.x yet.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen ok, however inside the link I provided looking at the typescript example, they mentioned about the system.config file which again I don't have within my project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That npm repo is using System.JS as their example module bundler.

angular-cli uses Webpack, but automatically manages the config file for you so you don't have to. Just skip the system.js step and you should just be able to use the package just fine.

Comment: Is that all that is different between System.JS and webpack?

Comment: System JS is just for loading modules. Webpack can also bundle up and uglify your modules, so I find it much better. Some people prefer SystemJS because it's more lightweight. And SystemJS used to be better for things like lazy loading sub-sections of your website, but Webpack 2 has now added support for that.